# Using a property as a qualifier for Dependency Injection in spring

Tags: spring

Is it possible to @Autowire a bean by name (ie. use a @Qualifier) but get the name of the bean from a property set by the BeanFactoryPostProcessor. So in short something like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(@Value("${name.of.my.object}")) 
private MyObject obj;
```

Assuming that there are more than one MyObject beans that have been created and there is a property called name.of.my.object=foo in my properties files read by the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Answer (score 2):

That would be nice, but I don't think you can do such a thing.

The closest I can think of is to define a bean alias in XML:

```
<alias bean="${name.of.my.object}" alias="myAlias"/>
```

and then refer to the alias in the qualifier:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myAlias") 
private MyObject obj;
```

Not very elegant, and I haven't actually tried it before, but I think it should work.